# TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'value') in vuejs3

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, dialog, quasar

I want to add a dialog component to my tableConfig.vue but it keep giving me this error:
Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'value')
TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'value') at openDialog
this is my dialog.vue component

```
<template>
 <div id="q-app" style="min-height: 100vh;">
  <div class="q-pa-md q-gutter-sm">
  <q-dialog v-model="prompt" persistent>
    <q-card style="min-width: 350px">
      <q-card-section>
        <div class="text-h6">Your address</div>
      </q-card-section>

      <q-card-section class="q-pt-none">
        <q-input dense v-model="address" autofocus @keyup.enter="prompt = false"></q-input>
      </q-card-section>
     </q-dialog>
    </div>
   </div>
 </template>

 <script setup lang="ts">
 import { ref } from 'vue';

 const prompt = ref(false);
 const address = ref('');

</script>
```

and this is where i want to use the dialog component :

```
        <template>
        <div class="q-pa-md">
        <q-table
            flat
            bordered
            title="Treats"
            :rows="rows"
            :columns="columns"
            row-key="name"
            :visible-columns="visibleColumns"
        >
                <!-- Add Button Inside q-select -->
                <q-btn
                flat
                round
                dense
                icon="add"
                @click= "openDialog"
                /> 
        </q-table>
        </div>
    </template>
    
    <script setup lang="ts">
    import { ref } from 'vue';
    import MyDialogComponent from './addElement.vue';

    const openDialog = () => {

        MyDialogComponent.prompt.value = true;
    }; 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seams to be using your dialog inside your parent template. You should try to address this issue first.

After that, rather than trying to access a child component's property directly, you should rely on props. It usually goes like this:

The parent component will define a reactive value and will pass this value, in a props, to it's child component

```html
<!-- parent component -->

<template>
  <ChildComponent :the-props="reactiveValue" />
</template>

<script setup>
  const reactiveValue = ref(false);
</script>
```

Then, the child component will define a props, to retrieve the value sent by the parent, and emit and events when it wants to mutate the props. This can be done easily by using a [writable computed property](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#writable-computed).

```
<!-- ChildComponent -->
<template>
  <input v-model="propsModel" />
</template> 

<script>
  const props = defineProps(['theProps']);
  const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue']);
  
  const propsModel = computed({
    get() {
      return props.theProps;
    },
    set(value) {
        emit('update:modelValue', value);
    }
  })
  
</script>
```

As you can see, when the `input` mutate the `propsModel`, the child component will emit an event ( `update-the-props` ), with the new value.

We can, then, listen to this event in the parent component and update the reactive value

```html
<!-- parent component -->

<template>
  <ChildComponent :the-props="reactiveValue" @update-the-props="handleThePropsUpdate" />
</template>

<script setup>
  const reactiveValue = ref(false);

  const handleThePropsUpdate = value => {
    reactiveValue.value = value;
  }
</script>
```

In your particular case, this allows the parent component to toggle the visibility of your dialog, without having to rely on the inner working of said dialog.